# Loading 2 million records in memory for batch is okay?

Tags: mongodb, spring-batch

I have to run a spring batch job. I have to read around 2 million documents from mongo. Documents have 15 fields fixed. They contain strings, dates and _id.

My question is, what is the best way to process this? Just do in 1 step or spread thru many steps? What is the best practice? Isn't loading 2 million records into memory bad? I know when loading records thru Apache spark, it streams data which is good. But I am not using Apache spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a chunk-oriented step. See [chunk-oriented processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) section of the docs.

Loading 2 millions records in-memory is not a good idea (even if you can manage to do it by adding more memory to your JVM) because you will have a single transaction to handle those 2 million records. If your job crashes let's say after processing 1 million records, the processing of this first half would be lost. The idea is to process documents in chunks and commit a transaction for every chunk. This type of precessing is:

- efficient: since it does not load the whole input data set in memory at once
- robust: since a job crash would not require you to reprocess the already processed documents

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Question: even with chunk processing, wouldn't itemreader still load 2 million records first?

Comment: Well, if you specify a chunk size of 2 millions, then yes :-). The item reader will only read `chunkSize` items in each iteration. Choosing the right chunkSize is an empirical process (because it depends on the document size for example in your use case), but a value between 100 and 1000 is a good start for most applications.